# Woocommerce - How Do You Save Cart Weight With Order?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need the cart weight to be saved with each order, to be retrieved later for generating UPS labels. I had this working, but I upgraded Woocommerce, now it's broke.

I can confirm that it's getting the order_id, but `$woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_weight` returns nothing.

Am I trying to get the cart weight after it's been emptied? At what point in the checkout process does the `$order_id` (aka `$post`) get created?

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'add_cart_weight');

function add_cart_weight( $order_id ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $weight = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_weight;
    update_post_meta($order_id, '_cart_weight', $weight);
}
```

Comment: Please contact the software vendor for your support options and then report back what they say to your many questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WC_Cart Docs](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Cart.html#1329) Prompt that there's a function to refresh the totals, try calling this before the `$weight`:

```
<?php
    function add_cart_weight( $order_id ) {
        global $woocommerce;
        $woocommerce->cart->calculate_totals();
        $weight = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_weight;
        update_post_meta($order_id, '_cart_weight', $weight);
    }
?>
```

> "Am I trying to get the cart weight after it's been emptied?"

Unfortunately not, The function just wants to increment the new total of the entire cart weight after a new item has been added, which subsequently updates the total weight record in the database by `update_post_meta` of column heading `meta_id` and `meta_value` of `$order_id`.